# Google now frequent crash

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, google-now

I have installed Google now in  CM 11 beta 5 running in htc explorer ,every time I make a search it freezes and crashes.I have rebooted again and again but no relief .it keeps on crashing.Can any one suggest me what to do

Comment: Can you try getting the logs of the crash?

Comment: how can I get the log?

Comment: CM 11 BETA <-- the word beta is a clue here, CM is generally quite buggy outside of stable releases. You'll have to raise a report with CM and see if it is a know issue and maybe a later build will address it. However, if you want a daily driver for your phone you are better off with a stable build of CM or another ROM. Otherwise you are nearly guaranteed to have issues. Alternatively, re-flash you gapps making sure you are using the correct KitKat ones from the CM site.